# Using the `mobility` gem with advanced PostgreSQL types like text[]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, mobility

We are using the [mobility gem](https://github.com/shioyama/mobility) to translate database content in a rails 6 app running on PostgreSQL, and we’re making use of advanced database types such as `text[]` (array of text).

Before installing mobility, this would be transparent to the app, i.e. it would act like a serialized column except without any actual serialization happening - you can transparently access the array in the record.

After installing mobility, we’re getting a string representation of the array back instead, e.g. instead of `["foo", "bar"]` we now get `[\"foo\", \"bar\"]` and the type is string, not array of string. I’m looking for a way to handle this case correctly - any pointers are appreciated. We’re using the key-value backend.

Comment: Hmm, if you're using the key-value backend, then you're not using any advanced database types, you're just using a string or text column (because those are the columns used in the `mobility_text_translations` and `mobility_string_translations` tables. If you wanted to have translated arrays, you could maybe try using the json backend or table backend, in the latter case you could modify the column type for the attribute on the table to be `array` and this should work (although I've never actually tried it).

Comment: This is a reasonable feature request, if you want to post an issue about it. It's likely that it's already supported in some form or other, but might be helpful to add documentation about it to the readme.